# Как запрограммировать поворот спрайта на произвольный угол относительно центра на языке программирования python 2.7.5

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.7, спрайт

У меня есть несколько вопросов. Я хочу сделать самонаводящиеся пули, разворачивающиеся к врагу лицом. Мои вопросы:

1. С помощью какого свойства можно повернуть спрайт на произвольный угол относительно центра на языке программирования Python 2.7.5?
2. Как, зная расстояние по обоим координатам между двумя спрайтами, вычислить направление одного из спрайтов? Прошу ответа на этот вопрос в виде формулы.

Мой язык программирования: Python 2.7.5

**Примечание: я хочу, чтобы предложить ответ на 2-й вопрос так, чтобы код был написан только через pygame, не используя numpy и прочие библиотеки!**

Comment: Может поможет pygame.transform.rotate()

Comment: Спасибо! А если ты знаешь расстояние по координатам между двумя спрайтами, как после этого вычислить направление, Vladimir?

Comment: Лучше отдельным вопросом задать, без привязки к языку программирования. Тут больше геометрия.

Comment: Vladimir, огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, то в pygame нельзя напрямую рассчитать угол. Без математических формул не обойтись, а для них нужны дополнительные библиотеки.

Можете легко установить numpy через pip.

Это дополнения к python с помощью 
которого можно легко загружать библиотеки.В ходе установки python оно загружается автоматически.

Попробуйте зайти в cmd и написать в командной строке "pip install numpy".

Если не получится или выдаст ошибку, значит у вас нету pip, переустановите python или самостоятельно загрузите pip(первый способ легче)

Есть ещё модуль math встроенный в питон, но у меня не работало, поэтому рекомендую numpy,

Comment: Ой( Я думал , что через pygame можно рассчитать угол( Ну ладно, спасибо за совет!

Comment: Я приму вот именно этот ответ и проголосую "за". Подарю вам +25 баллов репутации. Заодно разблокируйте много привилегий ;) я просто очень щедрый :D

Answer (score 1):

Для этого понадобится библиотека numpy.
Вот формула

x,y - позиция пули
centrx,centry - позиция относительно которой нужно поворачиватся

```
import numpy

def caltulate_angle(x,y,centrx,centry):
      deltax,seltay=centrx-x,centry-y
      angle=numpy.degrees(numpy.arctan2(deltay,deltax))
      return angle
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! А можно не через библиотеку numpy? И если нельзя, то как ее установить?

Comment: Ridgen, я имею в виду только через pygame

Comment: Из-за этого я вам пока не буду давать +15 баллов репутации, тем самым принимая ваш ответ. Я дал вам только +10, проголосовав "за".